# Android - Weird layout behaviour custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view, android-custom-view

I have a custom `ViewGroup` which has two children, a `ViewPager` and another subclass of `ViewPager`.

When I instantiate it from code, it displays fine. However, when doing so from XML, the second child was not showing. I confirmed by add other views above and below the custom `ViewGroup` from XML and it turns out that the view was vertically offsetting by some amount which led to the second child being truncated.

The measuring seemed fine since I got the correct gap between `t` and `b` in the `onLayout()`. So I tried the following in my `onLayout()` before calling `layout()` on the children.

```
b = b - t;
t = 0;
```

Voila.... its displays perfectly, which doesn't really make sense since there is a view above this one which means `t` being zero should overwrite it (or maybe its relative, I could be wrong).

Anyways, what bugging me is why the arguments to the `onLayout()` were obviously offsetting the view ?